# uniform convergance

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\chi={x_{1},x_{2},...} $ a dense subset of R. I need to construct a continuous curve in $X$ whose end points are $x_{1}$ and $x_{m}$ and its domain is [0,1]. We start with $\gamma_{1}:\left[ 0,1\right] \rightarrow X$ defined by $\gamma_{1}(t)=tx_{m}+(1-t)x_{1}$ for all $t\in\left[ 0,1\right] $.\
Note that $x_{1}=\gamma_{1}(0)$ and $x_{m}=\gamma_{1}(1)$, and $\gamma_{1}$ is the linear function joining these nodes. Also note that $\parallel\gamma_{1}(t)-\gamma_{1}(t^{\prime})\parallel=\mid t-t^{\prime}\mid\parallel x_{m}-x_{1}\parallel$ for all $t,t^{\prime}\in\left[ 0,1\right] $.
For each $j>1$, the new function $\gamma_{j}$ is obtained from $\gamma_{j-1}$ by adding an extra node between each pair of successive nodes of $\gamma_{j-1}$. The function $\gamma_{j}:\left[ 0,1\right]\rightarrow X$ is piecewise linear.\
Each new node in $\gamma_{j}$ is in $\chi$ and near the mid point of the segment joining successive nodes of $\gamma_{j-1}$. In fact, if $x\in X$ is the new node between successive nodes $\gamma_{j-1}(t_{1})$ and $\gamma_{j-1}(t_{2})$ of $\gamma_{j-1}$, we require that $$\parallel x-\gamma_{j-1}((t_{1}+t_{2})/2)\parallel<\epsilon_{j},$$
where the positive constant $\epsilon_{j}$ is chosen small enough so that 
\
$\parallel\gamma_{j}(t)- \gamma_{j}(t^{\prime}\prime)\parallel < 2 \mid t-t^{\prime}\mid\parallel x_{m}-x_{1}\parallel$ for all $0\leq t<t^{\prime}\leq1,$ and
$\parallel \gamma_{j}(t)-\gamma_{j-1}(t)\parallel<2^{-j}$ for all $t\in \left[ 0,1\right]$.\ How can I prove that the sequence of functions $\gamma_{n}$ converges uniformly to a continuous limit function $\gamma :[0,1]~ to~ X$?